# Batch input to a certain layer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on a network based on inception-v3 .I train the network successfully, and now I want to feed a batch of opencv images to  my network and get some output. 
The original placeholder of the network accepts a string and decodes it a jpg [(this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS0SS.png) But I read the video frames with opencv and convert them in a list of `nparray` :

```
  for cnt in range(batch_size):
        frameBuffer = []
        if (currentPosition >= nFrames):
            break
        ret, frame = vidFile.read()
        img_data = np.asarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        frameBuffer.append(img_data)
        currentPosition += multiplier
```

If  I want to work with a single images, beacuse i read frames directly from opencv, I convert them to np-array  and then feed it to "Cast:0" layer of the inception network:

```
pred = sess.run([predictions], {'Cast:0': img_data})
```

Results are OK to this point. But I want to feed a batch of frames: I tried to use `feed_dict` in the current way:

```
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size,width,height, 3])
image_batch = tf.stack(frameBuffer)

feed_dict = {images: image_batch}
avgRepresentation, pred = sess.run([pool_avg, predictions],{'Cast:0': feed_dict})
```

but i got errors; I know i have a mistake in feeding the batch. do you have any suggestion how i can feed a batch of images to a certain layer of a network ?

Comment: Can you give us the error you got ?

Comment: pred = sess.run([ predictions],{'Cast:0': feed_dict})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 954, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Answer (score 0):

There is (at least) a problem with your feed_dict: a feed_dict is typically a dictionary with tensors or strings (for tensor name) as keys, and the values (given as usual types, np arrays, etc.).

Here you're using `{'Cast:0': feed_dict}`, so the value of your dictionary is itself a dictionary, which makes no sense for tensorflow. You need to put the values there, i.e. the concatenation of the images (decoded, converted, etc.). Also, sorry if I'm missing something, but I guess that `frameBuffer` should contain all the images of the batch, so it should be initialized out of the `for` loop.

This code should work:

```
frameBuffer = []
for cnt in range(batch_size):
        if (currentPosition >= nFrames):
            break
        ret, frame = vidFile.read()
        img_data = np.asarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        frameBuffer.append(img_data)
        currentPosition += multiplier
avgRepresentation, pred = sess.run([pool_avg, predictions],{'Cast:0': np.asarray(frameBuffer)})
```